# Illustrator: Generate Array of Objects with random Properties like Length or Position

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, design-process, multiple-sizes

I am just trying to generate a pillar diagram within Illustrator. Since I want it to be very tiny and detailed, I want to use multiple Instances of one pillar with modified Properties, like length or position without having to place them manually.

Is there any possible way without creating an extra script for it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use a script? This sounds like the exact kind of situation where you would want to use a script.

Comment: Because I think this is a very generic function that should work in a more intuitiv way than applying a script each time I want to achieve this kind of result. Besides that I wasn't able to find a script that does randomness to my likings. If I start creating my own script now, it would take much more time compared to using a possible native function.